# The applications wasn't able to impersonate the user with the specified credentials

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, impersonation

My Code Functionality is as follows, It connects to a server with different credentials, traverses through the path in the server finds the file and downloads it in my Local.

I have used C# Impersonator() method for the same implementation. The Following the code block from which it is redirecting to the error.

```
using (new Impersonator(username, password, domain))
{
      // File Download Logic
}
```

I have been getting the following error message :

*The applications wasn't able to impersonate the user with the specified credentials!*

The credentials provided by me are correct.

Comment: _"It connects to a server with different credentials"_ - **exactly** what do you mean by "connects to a server"? Using what protocol? Are you referring to SMB or something involving Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: Have you checked your system's Security log for any relevant events? Is this an (on-prem) Active Directory-enabled network? Are you certain your AD User account has the necessary permissions (granted by AD and by Group Policy) to perform impersonation? How/where is your code running (IIS? IIS Express? Kestrel?) and what user-account or security context is _that_ running under?

Comment: And what is the "Impersonator()" method?

Comment: @Charlieface Impersonator method Docs : 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: What does that have to do with your `using (new Impersonator(username, password, domain))` Please show your actual code, as the object you are using is not in the docs.